# Razorpay Implementation

Tags: swift, razorpay

I have implemented the Razorpay according to the steps given by the Razorpay document for the iOS but when I try to open Razorpay screen, it is not opened. Please suggest me to successfully open the screen.

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: I am unable to open the Razorpay screen after implementing the whole code according to the steps given by the following link "https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/ios-integration/standard/". When I click on the button to reach Razorpay screen, I came back to the same screen and the last message which I got in the console is - /Users/travis/build/razorpay/razorpay-ios/RazorpayIOS/CheckoutOtpelf/Classes/RazorpayCheckoutVC.swift deinitialized

Comment: A FAILURE message is displayed - "Payment Failed - Unexpected Error". I am unable to reach the Razorpay screen.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

Keep in mind that razorpay accept payment in Paisa only, so if you want to make payment of INR 100.5, you have to pass 10050. Now if the value is INR 100.457, you have to floor it and pass 10046 only, 10045.7 won't accepted.

Case 2:

Please check your navigation bar status. This issue might help you https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-pod/issues/42

Comment: I have already done all the possible solutions given in the link but it won't help. May you please suggest another solution.